# Ormap version in "Realm Of Racket"

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, racket

In "Realm of Racket", the authors build a built-in function for educational purposes.

Their implementation of ormap is:

```
(define (my-ormap-book pred lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) #f]
        [else (or (pred (first lst))
                  (my-ormap-book pred (rest lst)))]))
```

This code seems to work fine in many cases, like the unit-tests bellow show:

```
(require rackunit)
(check-equal? (my-ormap-book add1 '(3 4 5)) 4)
(check-equal? (my-ormap-book add1 '()) #f)
(check-equal? (my-ormap-book positive? '(1 2 a)) #t)
```

However, the real Ormap, like racket documentation shows - [link](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=ormap#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._ormap%29%29) - also works with two or more lists as inputs, like:

```
(check-equal? (ormap + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) 5)
```

When doing that test with "Realm of Racket"s implementation, you get:

```
(check-equal? (my-ormap-book  + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) 5)

my-ormap-book: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 2
  given: 3
  arguments...:
```

How do I solve this?
How do I make the "my-ormap-book" procedure pass on this test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the built-in ormap handles multiple lists. I think I would separate your question into two questions. First: how do you define a function that takes a variable number of arguments (known as 'variadic')? Second: how do you define a variadic ormap?

In answer to the first: there are a couple of ways of defining variadic functions. The simplest is to use a dot in the argument list, before the last argument:

```
(define (f a b . rest-args)
  (first rest-args))
```

All arguments after the first two are bundled into a list with the given name.

This totally useless function accepts two or more arguments, and returns the third one (okay, pointless *and* broken).

In answer to your other question... well, this is a question of simultaneous recursion over multiple lists of the same length, and I think I'd refer you to [section 23.1 of HtDP 2e](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_four.html#%28part._sec~3atwo-inputs~3acase1%29).